# Why pyspark.sql lower function not accept literal col name and length function do?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Why in the next example the lower function not accept the col name as a literal and the length do?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Tom', 80)], ["name", "height"])
df.select (df.name, func.length('name')).show()
df.select (df.name, func.lower('name')).show()
```

---

```
+----+------------+
|name|length(name)|
+----+------------+
| Tom|           3|
+----+------------+

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method lower([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
....
```

In the documentation [pyspark.sql.length](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.length) sais that accept a column as parameter and the [pyspark.sql.lower](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lower) sais same. Why don't accept 'name'?

If I change for

```
df.select (df.name, func.lower(func.col('name'))).show()
```

run ok

```
+----+-----------+
|name|lower(name)|
+----+-----------+
| Tom|        tom|
+----+-----------+
```

Can someone explain me why?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. While Googling I landed on the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22212.

It appears to be a bug (minor) and the workaround seems to be what you actually did.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please post the relevant code to your answer directly, instead of posting a link. This will help the OP and others.